# smpt not sending email on published while working on localhost fine in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, smtp

**my code is**

```
WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
            //gmail port to send emails  
            WebMail.SmtpPort = 25;
            WebMail.SmtpUseDefaultCredentials = false;
            //sending emails with secure protocol  
            WebMail.EnableSsl = true;
            //EmailId used to send emails from application  
            WebMail.UserName = "myemail";
            WebMail.Password = "mypassword";

            //Sender email address.  
            WebMail.From = "myemail";

            //obj.EMailBody = "Dear" + query.FirstName + "Your password is: " + query.Password;

            //obj.EmailSubject = "Password Recovery";
            //WebMail.Send(to: obj.ToEmail, subject: obj.EmailSubject, body: obj.EMailBody, cc: obj.EmailCC, bcc: obj.EmailBCC, isBodyHtml: true);
            findThatUser.EMailBody = "Dear " + findThatUser.firstName + " " + findThatUser.lastName +" "+ "Your Key to reset Password is " + key;
            findThatUser.EmailSubject = "Password Recovery";
            WebMail.Send(to: findThatUser.emailAddress, subject: findThatUser.EmailSubject, body: findThatUser.EMailBody, isBodyHtml: true);
```

**in web.config my settings are**

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="sugarlydate@gmail.com">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="25" userName="myemail" password="mypassword" enableSsl="true" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

**Now when i try to send email on localhost so it works fine but when i try to send on my published website it doesn't work and not getting any error. Let me tell you lesssecureapps is turned in google settings**

Comment: port 25 != 587 ?? . BTW, if you set mailSettings, you don't need set again all props in your code.

Comment: Try adjust with same port number: `WebMail.SmtpPort = 587;`.

Comment: What is `WebMail`?

Comment: sorry for that, i have tried with the same ports but it didn't work

Comment: Port 25 is not likely to work on smtp.gmail.com : https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Comment: @rene i have tried with ports 587 and 465 but it didn't work